# How do I extract a value from a string in java that has been retrieved from a C# REST service

Tags: java, string, rest, tags

My problem is when I get a string from the REST service and set it as a string in java. It looks like this

```
<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">returnedValue</string>
```

How should I go about extracting the returnedValue from this?

Comment: I think this regex `>(.*?)<` will work. It will work only if the example string you have shown has same format everytime or `st.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is just an XML fragment (or document by itself) so to get the value you will need to parse it. You can do so by many different means but for this specific case maybe the best option is to use something like:

```
String str = // Your string from the REST service
int start = str.indexOf("\">");
int end = str.indexOf("</string>", start);
String returnedValue = str.substring(start + "\">".length(), end);
```

Other options would be to use a regular expression or an XML parser.